# In which fields Root Systems are useful? And why?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, lie-algebras

I've studied [Root Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system) to classify Lie Algebras and the construction emerged pretty naturally. Anyway I've been said that Root Systems are applied in other fields and are a useful tool in classify other algebric structure.

If anybody knows something about I'd like to have some hint on both where Root Systems apply and if there some kind of general idea of why they're so useful.

Comment: Hmm, so quantum groups spring to mind (though they are of course closely related). As do Coxeter groups, though only those related to Lie algebras are also directly related to root systems anyway.

Comment: Root systems also appear in algebraic combinatorics, in the study of singularities, and in theoretical physics ("ADE"). Of course, Lie theory is the primary "field" (I suppose you do not refer to the field as a"field". If so, root system are useful in any field of characteristic zero).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Though they also show up in positive characteristic (though they still themselves "live" in  characteristic $0$).

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes was a soft question of this kind (field was not in the algebric sense :D ) if anyone can write even only few lines as answer or some kind of reference I will be glad to upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Root systems are one of the most remarkable structures elucidated in 20th century mathematics. They have a simple definition in terms of linear algebra and combinatorics, but have very far reaching applications in many areas of mathematics and physics. Most notably root systems appear in the classification of Lie groups and Lie algebras, algebraic groups, in representation theory of Lie algebras, Reflection Groups and Coxeter Groups, in hypergeometric functions, Macdonald conjectures, Selberg integrals, in the structure theory of reductive groups, and in the theory of symmetric spaces, just to name a few. For references see also [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49008/complex-root-systems).

Comment: Also, quiver representations of finite type, and cluster algebras of finite type are classified by ADE Dynkin diagrams (which are of course closely related to root systems)